# Flex - Missing constructor arguments in an included swc lib

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, swc

I've written a swc lib using flash pro cs6. Among others the swc contains "LPChat" class:

```
package {
import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON;

import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.net.URLRequestHeader;
import flash.utils.setInterval;

public class LPChat extends Sprite {
    private var _sessionKey:String;
    private var chatEvents:ChatEvents;
    private var links:Object;
    private var info:Object;

    public function LPChat(chatObj:Object) {
.....
    }
}
```

when included in a flash pro projects all works fine, but when included in a flex project I get the following error:

Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on LPChat(). Expected 0, got 1.

which is strange because the constructor does expect 1 and not 0 arguments. I can see the same behavior inside the flash builder IDEA:

[image]

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Re-compile the swc with a proper IDE or even with the [compc](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fd2.html) compiler itself

Comment: Remove constructor argument. Error message : Expected 0, got 1 !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the default package caused the problem. when I moved it to com.lp all issues where solved.

Comment: I think you somehow fixed something else in the process. I just tried to recreate your issue in the main package and it works as expected. I didn't use Flash Pro to compile it though, but I assume it uses compc under the hood.